# 403 Error while getting box api access token

Tags: box-api

Helllo i am integrating box application into my application. I followed the API doc but i am facing a problem while fetching an access token. It gives me error of 403 forbidden. I am using the following url:

```
 https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=YOUR_AUTH_CODE&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
```

i am having this in return

Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 16 Dec 2013 16:46:33 GMT
Server: nginx

Comment: The URL you posted completes the OAuth2 workflow. Did you first authenticate the user by sending them to: https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID

Comment: yeah i did i redirected user to https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?

Comment: Maybe post a little bit more about what you are doing (with code snippets) so someone can help you.

Comment: i want to integrate box with i need access token with this url but it return 403 error

Comment: Did you make this call within the short window that the Auth-Code is valid?  If you did figure this out, it would be great to post a followup on how you solved it.  Even if it was just an oversight on setting a parameter in the language you were implementing, code samples will help others in the future.